# Pandas Apply with Change in Function's Input

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

Let assume I have this simple function where it finds the maximum number between a variable x and the comparison value (can be anything).

```
def find_max(x, comparison_value = 2):
    if x > comparison_value:
        y = x
    else:
        y = comparison_value
    
    return y
```

I would like to apply this function to a data frame:

```
abcd = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,5],[3,4]], columns= ['col1','col2'])

   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     2     5
2     3     4

abcd.col1.apply(find_max)
```

My question is: is there a way for me to also alter the function's input when I use pandas.apply? For example, now I want to change the comparison value equals to 3 instead of 2. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need pass argument `**kwargs` in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

> Define a custom function that takes keyword arguments and pass these arguments to apply.

```
def add_custom_values(x, **kwargs):

    for month in kwargs:

        x += kwargs[month]

    return x

s.apply(add_custom_values, june=30, july=20, august=25)
London      95
New York    96
Helsinki    87
dtype: int64
```

So in your solution use:

```
print (abcd.col1.apply(find_max, comparison_value=3))
```